# Django exclude field from '__all__' in DjangoFilterBackend for ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have multiple API classes (of `ModelViewSet`) that are inheriting from one common `ViewSet`.
So there are different kinds of models with their own fields but all share the same features that are defined in the common `viewset`.

One of those features - is filtering. It looks like this:

```
class CommonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = '__all__'

class FirstViewSet(CommonViewSet):
    model = FirstModel

class SecondViewSet(CommonViewSet):
    model = SecondModel

# etc...
```

Each model has a different set of fields, except that each model has a common field `user`. I don't want this field to be exposed in any way.

I have excluded this field from the serializers:

```
class CommonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('user',)

class SecondSerializer(CommonSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FirstModel

# etc...
```

What I want to achieve is to **exclude** the field `user` from `filter_fields` of `CommonViewSet` as well. I.e.:

```
filter_fields = '__all__' # except 'user'
```

Is there a standard way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by myself.

To do so I defined `CustomFilterBackend` which expands the functionality of `DjangoFilterBackend` with `filter_exclude`:

```
class CustomFilterBackend(DjangoFilterBackend):
    def get_filterset_class(self, view, queryset=None):
        filterset = super().get_filterset_class(view, queryset)
        
        filter_exclude = getattr(view, 'filter_exclude', None)
        for x in filter_exclude:
            filterset.base_filters.pop(x, None)
        return filterset
```

So with such filter backend I can define on my `ModelViewSet` the additional field for excluded fields:

```
class UserCustomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (CustomFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = '__all__'
    filter_exclude = ('user',)
```